# visual studio 2013 debug iterator container

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm doing a lot of debugging dealing with iterators right now, and wanted to know if anybody knew a simple way to get a watch variable with all of the elements in the container being referenced by the iterators, as the functions only have access to the iterators and not the containers themselves.

Maybe some way to enumerate starting from the iterator and the next x elements?

Comment: For Debug builds, the VS standard library containers' iterator types have a pointer back to the parent container. If you dig through their implementation, you *might* be able to figure out how to create a local variable that points to the container, and then watch its contents. However, the request seems a bit odd to me. If the function you're debugging takes iterators, then you should only care about what the iterator currently points to, not the following/preceding elements.

Comment: @Praetorian thanks, ill take a look at that. However, you try debugging sorting functions without being able to see the order of elements between calls 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Praetorian mentioned, in VS you can enumerate the values of the pointer to see the contents of the container your iterator is iterating over.

A watch variable like:

```
(MyIterator)._Ptr, 5
```

or

```
(MyIterator)._Ptr, NumElements
```

will enumerate the first NumElements elements in the container.